# MS Edge: overflow: hidden not working on box-shadow

Tags: html, css, overflow, microsoft-edge, box-shadow

I have applied a large `box-shadow` to a `position: absolute` `<div>`. Its parent `<div>` has `overflow: hidden` set which (from my understanding) should hide any overflowing `box-shadow` – and this works just fine on Chrome but for some reason not on MS Edge.

See the example here:

```css
.outerbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  display: table;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shadowbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="shadowbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8u43mztw/

When viewed on Chrome it appears as one would expect like this:

[image: Viewed on Chrome]

But when viewed on MS Edge it appears as follows:

[image: Viewed on MS Edge]

For some reason on Edge, setting `overflow: hidden` on the box parent to the box on which the `box-shadow` has been applied has no effect. Chrome has no trouble hiding the overflowing `box-shadow`. Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox also. Try to remove `display: table;` from `.innerbox`: in Firefox works fine.

```css
.outerbox {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

.innerbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shadowbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox">
    <div class="shadowbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect - works great. Not exactly sure why this was the problem...but looks like it's all resolved now.